# server.js File cannot access .env.local variable

Tags: next.js

I'm using Next.js v14.1.1 and I'm having trouble getting environment variables.
I made a custom server for https in server.js and applied it to package.json.
I wanted to get PORT, HOST information from environment variables, but it didn't work.
used `npm run dev` to start my project local, in a https server.

I'm quite new to Next.js so I might be missing something here...

```
// package.json
{
    //...
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "node server.js",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start -p 15100",
        "lint": "next lint"
    },
    //...
}
```

```js
// server.js
const { createServer } = require("https");
const { parse } = require("url");
const next = require("next");
const fs = require("fs");

//tried all below but didn't work -> shows `undefined`
//const port = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PORT;
//const port = process.env.PORT;
//const domain = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN;
//const domain = process.env.DOMAIN;

const port = 12345;
const domain = "localhost";
const dev = true;
const app = next({ dev, domain, port });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("./certificate/test.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./certificate/test.crt"),
};

app.prepare().then(() => {
    createServer(httpsOptions, async (req, res) => {
        const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
        handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
    }).listen(port, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`> HTTPS: Ready on https://${domain}:${port}`);
    });
});
```

```
// .env.local
NEXT_PUBLIC_PORT=12345
NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN=localhost
PORT=12345
DOMAIN=localhost
```

`.env.local's variables doesn't seem to work in server.js with or without `NEXT_PUBLIC` prefix

my directory structure is like this:

```
<PROJECT-FOLDER>
⊢.git
⊢.idea
⊢.next
⊢certificate
⊢node_modules
⊢public
⊢src
⊢.env.local
⊢.gitignore
⊢jsconfig.json
⊢next.config.js
⊢next.config.mjs
⊢package.json
⊢package-lock.json
⊢README.md
⌞server.js
```

By reading docs, I put .env.local file at ROOT directory, but somehow it was undefined by runtime.
Any information or suggestions would be appreciated.

---

(+) I've tried again and found out that when the app is prepared in `app.prepare().then(()=>{})` you should be able to access process.env variables. Before that, you can't access.

So I my codes, the `const app = next({ dev, domain, port });` was forced to have local variables in the parameter since app isn't prepared yet.

But some codes could be fixed, like below

```js
// server.js
const { createServer } = require("https");
const { parse } = require("url");
const next = require("next");
const fs = require("fs");

//tried all below but didn't work -> shows `undefined`
//const port = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PORT;
//const port = process.env.PORT;
//const host = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST;
//const host = process.env.HOST;

const port = 12345;
const domain = "localhost";
const dev = true;
const app = next({ dev, domain, port });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("./certificate/test.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./certificate/test.crt"),
};

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const portEnv = process.env.PORT;
    const hostEnv = process.env.DOMAIN;

    createServer(httpsOptions, async (req, res) => {
        const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
        handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
    }).listen(, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`> HTTPS: Ready on https://${hostEnv}:${portEnv}`);
    });
});
```

and the console would print `> HTTPS: Ready on https://localhost:12345`

---

I tried to use Next.js .env.local variables in server.js that was used to start the app, and it didn't work.
I read Next.js docs but couldn't find what was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you might know, NextJS uses babel to convert the `process.env.XXX` syntax to the real value inside your `.env` files during the build time. However, as per the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server):

> **server.js doesn't go through babel or webpack.** Make sure the syntax and sources this file requires are compatible with the current node version you are running.

It means that we don't have babel or webpack while running the `server.js`. In fact, `server.js` will be run using the node directly inside our package.json scripts: `node server.js`. So there is not any conversion for the environment variables.

**But what is the solution?**
This is an example from the official documentation:

```js
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')
 
// LOOK HERE: we are using NODE_ENV
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = 'localhost'
const port = 3000
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
 
app.prepare().then(() => {
  ... 
})
```

Now, how we can access it? To do that, you have to set this env explicitly inside your script in package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
}
```

So, to be able to access more variables (e.g. PORT, etc.) it would be something like this:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production PORT=3000 HOST=localhost node server.js"
}
```

**NOTE:** Setting the environment variables like this, only works on Linux (and maybe MacOS, I'm not sure) but does not work on Windows. On Windows, you have to use a package like [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

**NOTE 2:** With this way, you have to push your environment variables beside your code to your GitHub repository or any hosting you are using. It means, that they won't be really secure. Make sure you are not using sensitive variables.

**BONUS:** Setting a variable as I said earlier could be a little hard and dirty. Another way to set those variables is to write them in a `.env` file like `server.env` and read them using an env parser such as [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). This also gives you a little more security, because you can put the `server.env` out of your source file and put it manually on your server, so it won't stay in your GitHub, git history, or anywhere else.